# Logic operator syntax in VB for my School Project

Tags: vb.net

so I'm writing a Blackjack game for my Advanced Higher Computing Science project at school, and I have a question about the syntax of the logical operators in VB.

Here's the situation..

```
If X>Y AND (A=True Or B=True Or C=True) Then
   Do something 
End IF
```

Let's say for instance that X is indeed greater than Y, and A is true, but B and C are false. As I understand it the statement will execute, because X is greater than Y, AND at least one of the conditions within the brackets is true, but I'm not entirely sure if this is correct. Can the brackets be used this way for things to be logically correct? Or do I have to write conditions regarding A, B and C separately? For example...

```
If X>Y AND A=True Then 
   Do something
End IF   

If X>Y AND B=True Then 
   Do something
End IF

If X>Y AND C=True Then 
   Do something
End IF
```

Basically, can the brackets be used as a 'short hand' method to make the code slightly shorter and less cluttered? I'm using the latest version of VB, 2015.

Thanks a lot for any help, I appreciate it!

P.S. - I can't put my actual code on the internet, as this could get me in trouble with my exam board as this is an official assessment.

Comment: Yes, as per your statement, it seems ok. Did you actually try to run your code? Did you face any issue? I guess, your `=` actually mean `==`, isn't it?

Comment: No, because if in your second snippet more than one out of `A` or `B` or `C` is true, the code `Do something`will be executed more than once.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help! Yeah I ran it, but I got an error and I suspected it could be a problem with the syntax I was using. I'll take another look at it.

Comment: @WeatherVane very true, but only in case where `Do Something`s are actually different, and I _assume_ that's not what OP is doing.

Comment: @SouravGhosh but OP was equating it with the first snippet, which it is not.

Comment: If OP is unsure of operator precedence (as I am with VB without looking it up) the brackets in the first snippet are good.

Comment: If the braces enclose an expression it is fine to do, and can make the logic more easily read.

Comment: You also don't need `=True` in your statements.

Comment: @sourav no vb.net uses = for ==

Comment: Off-topic but I would suggest that you always use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` by default in VB.NET and only use `And` and `Or` when you specifically need to avoid short-circuiting, which should be pretty much never.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this original example

```
If X>Y AND (A=True Or B=True Or C=True) Then
```

It says, that 2 conditions must be met to evaluate this to `True`. `X` must be more than `Y` and also, condition in parenthesis must evaluate to `True`. First, lets optimize your code to use .net efficiently

```
If X>Y AndAlso (A OrElse B OrElse C) Then
```

In your case, if `X>Y` evaluates to `False` there is no reason to continue. Hence, `AndAlso`. This is a shortcut. Same with `OrElse`. If `A` evaluates to true, we don't need to evaluate other conditions - this is supported by your logic. Now, `A=True` - this is noise. And this is why you name Boolean variables, `isSomething, hasSomething, [doneSomething]`, where `doneSomething` is a verb, i.e. `created, completed, disposed, allowed`.

Now, lets look at your second piece of code. Obviously what comes into view first, is that you re-evaluating `X>Y` 3 times and along, you may do `Do something` 3 times. This syntax widely used but it would be something along these lines (to create same logic as first evaluation)

```
If Not X>Y Then 
   Return ' exit because your first evaluation must be true
End If

If A Then
   ' Do something
   Return ' Success and return
End If

If B Then
   ' Do something
   Return ' Success and return
End If

If C Then
   ' Do something
   Return ' Success and return
End If
```

Of course, **the code above makes little sense** because there is obvious repetition. This is better

```
If Not X>Y Then 
   Return ' exit because your first evaluation must be true
End If

If A OrElse B OrElse C Then
   ' Do something
End If
```

This makes more sense but then again, go to line #2 and use optimized single line code - it will do same.